# Fixed position CSS for a button to provide website feedback

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, css

I want to create a fixed position button that will run on my site, either on the left hand side or as a popout panel (see http://uservoice.com/fullservice for a cool popout button at the bottom of the screen). Clicking on the button will launch a popup window that my company uses for contact and feedback information.

Is there a basic example CSS for these types of buttons? I am a JS guy and created the popup window with no problems, but I don't have the CSS skills to get the button to activate my window.

Answer (score 10):

the css would be:

```
.button {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0; //or left: 0; depending on where you want it to be.
}
```

with html being:

```
<div class='button'> button text here </div>
```

Answer (score 6):

Try something like this:

```
#feedback-button {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}
```